# VCO sinusoidal output design

Tags: ltspice, vco

I want to design a VCO with a range between 1Khz - 100Khz. I am following the design from another forum [Low frequency in this VCO design](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/514516/low-frequency-in-this-vco-design). I ended up changing c1 to 7pf which changes the range form 33.9Khz to 99Khz with a 1V-12V input. The upper limit is alright but I am having trouble changing the lower one to 1Khz. I also want to know what kind circuit this is so I can find some theory related to it. Finally if I want to get a sinusoidal output would I just integrate the signals coming out of the square or triangle waves? And how would I know what values of resistors and capacitors to use? Thanks a lot in advance. I have attached a picture of my design below.[image]

Comment: I didn't see any mention of the op-amp part number. If you need a sinewave output then start with a sinewave oscillator is my advice.

Comment: You are trying to design a VCO with 6.6 octaves of tuning range. This is ... quite ambitious. One way might be to design a VCO that can tune from 50 to 100 kHz. Then add a divide by 2 circuit to get the range from 25 to 50 kHz. Then add another divide by 2 to get the range from 12 to 25 kHz. And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can squash the triangle wave through a nonlinear network of some kind to get a sine-like output. If you need a very clean sine wave this is not a good way to do it.

The venerable HP3311A function generator, which you might want to research for your project, does it like this:

[image: HP3311A Sine Waveshaper]

In analog synthesizers this is commonly done with a spare LM13700 section. Not perfect, but totally fine for its intended purpose. Sine shape can be further refined with trimpots in place of R2/R3/R4.
[image: LM13700 Sine Waveshaper Schematic]
[image: LM13700 Sine Waveshaper Output]

As for the frequency range, you might consider a range switch that switches a different capacitor value into the circuit.